# Ongoing trouble with I2C on Atmega328p

Tags: c, atmega, i2c

I've the following schematic :

[image]

the Harness connector goes to [TCA9548A](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tca9548a.pdf)  as followed:

[image]

based on the datasheet of the IC, the address is **0x70** and it can run with **100kHz** or **400kHz**. I've run this code on the uC :

```
    #define F_CPU 8000000UL
#define SCL_CLOCK 400000   // I've tried both 100khz too
#define BAUD 9600
#define MYUBRR    F_CPU/8/BAUD-1
#define TWIMUX  0x70 


#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <util/twi.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>


void init_i2c(void ) {
     uint8_t   twst;
     char add  = 0x70; 
     short i = 0 ; 
     TWSR = 0;                         // no prescaler
     TWBR = ((F_CPU/SCL_CLOCK)-16)/2; 
     TWCR = (1<<TWINT)|(1<<TWSTA )|(1<<TWEN);

     printf("TWCR 0x%x \n",TWCR);
     while(!(TWCR & (1<< TWINT)));
     printf(" Start condition has been transmitted \n");
     if( (TWSR & 0xF8) != TW_START){
         printf(" TWSR start 0x%x\n",TWSR);
     }

        for  ( i  =0 ; i< 8 ; i++ ){  // After trying everything with 0x70 I tought the problem could be with the address 

     // Setting Address 
     TWDR = add; 
     // clearing TWCR 
     TWCR = (1<<TWINT) |(1<<TWEN);
     while (!(TWCR & (1<<TWINT)));
     twst = (TWSR&0xF8);
    if ((TWSR & 0xF8) != TW_MT_SLA_ACK){
         printf("Device address wrong  at TWSR   0x%x    SLA_ACK  0x%x  address 0x%x \n",twst, TW_MT_SLA_ACK,add);  // here is the problem !!!!!!!!!  TWSR value should be 0x18
         add++;
    }else {
        printf("device found at 0x%x   TWSR : 0x%x \n",add,TWSR);
    }
    }
 }


.............................................


int main(void)
{
    unsigned short i = 0 ; 
      DDRD |= (1 << PD5);       // damit ist dann PB0 ein Ausgang
        // UART init and printf 
    init_uart(MYUBRR);
    stdout = &mystdout;

    init_i2c(); 
    while(1){
    }
    }
```

Here is the output that I get :

[image]

So  As you can see I don't get the ACK from the slave.

here is what I can see on the scope:

for 100Khz:

[image]

for 400kHz
[image]

Both measurements are for 0x70 address.
my question  is what I'm doing wrong here, and why are both SCL and SDA not on high despiste pull-up ?  is it a software setup that I'm missing ?

thanks for your help!

Comment: PD6 / I2C_R? I think your conclusion is correct, lines should be high when inactive. Disconnect I2C slave, and check if they're high then. You'll then know whether to look for issue on master or slave.

Comment: Beware using UARTs and I2C buses at the same time.  UARTs take a LONG time to shove data out (esp. when the printf() family of functions are used) and this might be enough to upset the timing of your I2C communications.  Some I2C devices do time-out if they are not happy with the Master's clocking behaviour.  I'm not saying it's a problem here but it's something to bear in mind.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a start bit.  The start bit is when SDA goes low while SCL remains high.  I think every new transaction begins with a start bit.  See P13/14 of the datasheet.  Maybe it's not shown (and off-left of the scope screen)?

Also. perhaps part of what dannyf said.  Try address 0xE0.
The I2C Address of your chip is indeed 0x70.  However this is only 7 bits wide.  Depending on the firmware implementation, one may need to left-shift this value by one, and or-in the read/write bit.

By your scope traces, it looks to me that you're sending and unshifted 0x70, and the result is being nak'd (no chip at that address).

To decipher the transmitted data in the scope traces, look at where the scl goes high, and the condition of sda (is it high or low).

To read from this chip, send 0xE1, then whatever (if any) other data.
To write from this chip, send 0xE0, then whatever to write.

This is where having a logic probe really, really helps.  There are many cheap (and not cheap) tools available.

Answer (score 0):

Try running an [i2c scanner code](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/I2cScanner) on your ATmega, to check if the address is correct.

This will list all the connected i2c device addresses.

There is also an [i2c master library here](https://github.com/DSSCircuits/I2C-Master-Library) that might make things easier.

Answer (score -2):

it couldn't have been I2c signaling. Maybe your scope's probe is placed wrong?

or maybe the twi module is in the wrong mode?

edit:

> the address is 0x70

0xe0.

Comment: thanks for replying but scope probe is definitely correct, but what do you mean with twi module Mode ?